# Improve accuracy with Tensorflow Object detection pretrained model

Tags: python, object, tensorflow, detection, object-detection

I am working on building an object detection model which I would like to create with 22 new classes (most of them are not in COCO or PETS datasets)
What I've already done is:

- Prepared images with multiple labels using LabelIMG.
- Decrease image size in 2 for images that are bigger than 500k
- Convert XML to CSV file
- Convert CSV and images to TFRecord
- Using the Tensorflow sample config files I've trained with several pretrained checkpoints.

**Results**: SSD_Mobilenet and SSD_Inception resulted in no classes
found(loss ~10.0) while faster RCNN Inception did succeed to detect some of the
objects(loss ~0.7).

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between train.py from [Object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), which I used in the above, to retrain.py from [image_retraining](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) to train_image_classifier.py from [Slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim)?
2. Which is better for my task? Or should I do it in a different way?
3. While running the train.py on FRCNN inception I found that the loss was around 0.7 and not going lower even after 100k steps. Is there any goal in terms of loss to achieve?
4. How do you suggest to change the config file to improve this?
5. I found other models for instance Inception V4 etc... which doesn't have sample config files - [TF slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim). Should I try them and if so how can I use them?

I am pretty new in this field and I need some support in understanding the terms and actions.

BTW: I am using GTX 1060 (GPU) for training but eval is not working in parallel so I can't get the mAP for validation. I tried to force eval for CPU but with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone?........

Answer (score 0):

1) What is the difference between train.py from Object detection, which I used in the above, to retrain.py from image_retraining to train_image_classifier.py from Slim

Ans : To what i know, none. Because train.py imports trainer.py which imports slim.learning.train(the same class which is used in train_image_classifier.py) to train.

2) Which is better for my task? Or should I do it in a different way?

Ans: The above answer answers this question too.

3) While running the train.py on FRCNN inception I found that the loss was around 0.7 and not going lower even after 100k steps. Is there any goal in terms of loss to achieve?

Ans: If you use tensorboard to visualize your results, you will find that when your classification loss graph is not changing a lot(has converged), your model is trained. Regarding the loss of 0.7, thats high after training for so many steps. Just check your pipeline config file parameters.

4) How you suggest to change the config file to improve this?

Ans: Learning rate value can be a good start

5) I found other models for instance Inception V4 etc... which doesn't have sample config files - TF slim ? Should I try them and if som how can I use them?

Ans: currently, I dont have an answer for this. but will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a complete answer, but I hope it helps in some way!)

Are your annotated objects small relative to the image size?
I had the same problems with no or few detections with SSD and found that model is very sensitive to the setting which determines the size of the box proposals (anchor generator). Here is a [link with some details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595240/map-decreasing-with-training-tensorflow-object-detection-ssd/48846506#48846506)

Further, having an active eval job running is very important when debugging and tuning a model. TotalLoss or any of the parameters returned from the train job does not inform you of the performance of the actual model, only whether it is converging. The eval job gives you e.g. mAP which is a real measure of performance.

A simple way to force an eval job on cpu is by doing the following:

a) install a virtual environment dedicated for the eval job, [instructions here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv)

b) activate the virtual environment and install tensorflow cpu in the virtual environment (yes, you should install tensorflow again, and without gpu support)

c) start the train job as usual on your tensorflow-gpu (in whatever way you have installed it)

d) run the eval job in the virtual environment (this will force it to run on the cpu and works great! I also run tensorboard from this installation to minimise risk of interference with the train job)

Answer (score 0):

Retrain is used to add a level in top of pretrained model... You can win time like this.. Useful for thousand of picture, useless for million labelised picture... Less efficient than train from skratch. There is template for config file. If thereis not config file create your own.. Look at tensorflow github explainations...